# Combining split() and cumsum()

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I am trying to produce stats for cumulative goals by season by a particular soccer player. I have used the cut function to obtain the season from the game dates. I have data which corresponds to this dataframe

```
df.raw <-
    data.frame(Game = 1:20,
            Goals=c(1,0,0,2,1,0,3,2,0,0,0,1,0,4,1,2,0,0,0,3),     
               season = gl(4,5,labels = c("2001", "2002","2003", "2004")))
```

In real life, the number of games per season may not be constant

I want to end up with data that looks like this

```
df.seasoned <-
    data.frame(Game = 1:20,seasonGame= rep(1:5),
            Goals=c(1,0,0,2,1,0,3,2,0,0,0,1,0,4,1,2,0,0,0,3),
            cumGoals = c(1,1,1,3,4,0,3,5,5,5,0,1,1,5,6,2,2,2,2,5),     
               season = gl(4,5,labels = c("2001", "2002","2003", "2004")))
```

With the goals cumulatively summed within year and a game number for the season

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another job for `ddply` and `transform` (from the `plyr` package):

```
ddply(df.raw,.(season),transform,seasonGame = 1:NROW(piece),
                                 cumGoals = cumsum(Goals))
   Game Goals season seasonGame cumGoals
1     1     1   2001          1        1
2     2     0   2001          2        1
3     3     0   2001          3        1
4     4     2   2001          4        3
5     5     1   2001          5        4
6     6     0   2002          1        0
7     7     3   2002          2        3
8     8     2   2002          3        5
9     9     0   2002          4        5
10   10     0   2002          5        5
11   11     0   2003          1        0
12   12     1   2003          2        1
13   13     0   2003          3        1
14   14     4   2003          4        5
15   15     1   2003          5        6
16   16     2   2004          1        2
17   17     0   2004          2        2
18   18     0   2004          3        2
19   19     0   2004          4        2
20   20     3   2004          5        5
```

Comment: FYI `transform` is part of base R, `summarize` is part of `plyr`

Answer (score 6):

```
 df.raw$cumGoals <- with(df.raw,  ave(Goals, season, FUN=cumsum) )
 df.raw$seasonGame <- with(df.raw,  ave(Game, season, FUN=seq))
 df.raw
```

Or with transform ... the original transform, that is:

```
df.seas <- transform(df.raw, seasonGame = ave(Game, season, FUN=seq),
                          cumGoals = ave(Goals, season, FUN=cumsum) )
df.seas
   Game Goals season seasonGame cumGoals
1     1     1   2001          1        1
2     2     0   2001          2        1
3     3     0   2001          3        1
4     4     2   2001          4        3
5     5     1   2001          5        4
6     6     0   2002          1        0
7     7     3   2002          2        3
8     8     2   2002          3        5
9     9     0   2002          4        5
10   10     0   2002          5        5
snipped
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually found this simpler to follow +1

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `data.table` which is very fast.

```
library(data.table)
df.raw.tab = data.table(df.raw)
df.raw.tab[,list(seasonGame = 1:NROW(Goals), cumGoals = cumsum(Goals)),'season']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I may compare times if I have large dataframe